Linux bash/script - how can I use an alias defined outside of the script?
In my .bashrc I have:
alias pbcopy='xsel --clipboard --input'

Then, in my one_script.sh I have:
#!/bin/bash

readlink -f myfile | pbcopy

And, I get the below error:
./one_script.sh: line 3: pbcopy: command not found

Any suggestions on how to make this work? (see answer below)
THE ANSWER IS HERE:
Linux bash/script - how can I use an alias defined outside of the script?

Use bash functions and export them with export -f function_name instead of aliases. In general, functions are also more versatile.

I suggest to write scripts in a way to not rely on alias or function definition from the user's Shell startup files. Better include everything in the script or in a central file that belongs to your project.

@Bodo, is that so, that the script becomes stand alone and does not break? :)

@Atti I don't understand what you want to ask in your last comment. You could ask a separate question in which you show the script and the alias definition if you need help to make your script stand-alone. Please don't edit an answer into your question. Normally you can write an answer to your own question, but this is not possible if the question is closed. The linked answer is already shown in the box above the question.
